# Get System Date when passing System.DateTime.Now in a Textbox as an string variable

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
DateTime currentdate;
int result;
try
{
    // EXAMPLE: 2012-04-15 15:23:34:123 
    DateTime backupdate =
       DateTime.ParseExact(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", //mind the casing
         TextBox1.Text,
         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Response.Write(backupdate);
    currentdate = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);
    result = currentdate.CompareTo(backupdate);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

where **TextBox1.Text** contains "**System.DateTime.Now**" as **string** . So, I need to get system date in **backupdate**.

how should I do any One help?? Thanks...

Comment: Can you provide more information exactly what you want. I mean what is your expected result and what you are getting currently?

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your concern, I need current datetime as "2018-09-25 12:34:33" but it returning string in "System.DateTime.Now" which making the exception

Comment: Try using this `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss")`

Comment: Thank you Gaurav for ur approach. But I Need "System.DateTime.Now " is fetched from database to a string variable str. So how should I use this str so it should treated as System function of c# and return me the system date time.

Comment: @AnuragDigal, Did my answer help you with the issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing arguments to `ParseExact` in the wrong order.

So, assuming `TextBox.text` contains some `DateTime` value, then Instead of:

```
DateTime backupdate = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", TextBox1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It should be:

```
DateTime backupdate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```